Finitely dominated universal spaces for the family of solvable subgroups
$\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}\DeclareMathOperator\Sz{Sz}$In short, I am interested in the question which finite groups $G$ admit a finitely dominated universal space with respect to the family of solvable subgroups. That is, for which finite groups does there exist a finitely dominated $G$-CW complex $X$ such that for a subgroup $H \leq G$ one has

$X^H$ is contractible if $H$ is solvable;
$X^H$ is empty if $H$ is not solvable.

Of course, if $G$ is solvable then the point has all the desired properties. More examples can be found in the literature. I will first mention Adem's general work and then a classical construction of Floyd–Richardson.

In his article Finite group actions on acyclic $2$-complexes, Adem answers the question which finite simple groups $G$ can act on a finite acyclic $2$-complex without fixed points. He constructs explicit examples of $G$-complexes $X$ such that $X^H$ is acyclic if $H$ is solvable, and empty if $H$ is not solvable. Taking the join of such an example with itself (that is, the homotopy pushout of $X \leftarrow X \times X \rightarrow X$) gives a finite model for the universal space for the family of solvable subgroups of $G$.
In total, Adem's result show that a finite model exists for three infinite families of finite groups. They are:

$\PSL_2(2^k)$ for $k$ at least $2$;
$\PSL_2(q)$ for $q \geq 5$ congruent to $\pm3$ mod $8$;
$\Sz(2^k)$ for $k\geq 3$ odd.


Using work of Floyd–Richardson, one can construct a finite $A_5$-CW complex modeling the universal space for the family of solvable subgroups. Note that every proper subgroup of $A_5$ is solvable. The alternating group $A_5$ includes into $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ as the icosahedral subgroup. The coset space $\operatorname{SO}(3)/A_5$ (the Poincaré homology sphere) carries a left $A_5$-action with a single fixed point. Taking out that fixed point and collapsing to a $2$-skeleton gives rise to an $A_5$-action on an acyclic $2$-complex without fixed point. Smith-theoretic methods show that each solvable subgroup of $A_5$ has to have a fixed point, and the fixed point space is acyclic as well (see Thm. 3.1. in Adem's aforementioned article). Again, take the join of this $A_5$-space with itself.

In total, it seems like for quite a few finite simple groups $G$ there is a finitely dominated $G$-space modeling the universal space for the family of solvable subgroups. Are there more examples? Is there a finite group $G$ for which there exists no such space?

Are you aware of the work of Bob Oliver, in particular his article `Fixed-Point Sets of Group Actions of Finite Acyclic Complexes', Comment. Math. Helvetici Volume 50 (1975) 155-177?  He classifies the finite groups that can act without a fixed point on a finite acyclic complex.  The situation is quite different from the 2-dimensional case that you mention in your question.  His article does not consider universal spaces with respect to any family, but the techniques he uses should be relevant.

@GeoffRobinson yes, thanks, changed it!

Regarding the last question: It seems like one could construct such examples using cohomological dimension. If $G$ is a finite non-solvable group with a maximal solvable subgroup $N$ which is normal, then Lemma 5.2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.01692 implies that the cohomological dimension of $G$ with respect to the family of solvable subgroups is infinite.

@MarkGrant: I don’t think that’s possible, is it? Any cyclic subgroup of $G/N$ will have solvable preimage in $G$ that contains $N$.

The following was brought to my attention by Christoph Winges. In his work in smooth group actions on discs, Bob Oliver shows that for a compact Lie group $G$ there exists a smooth action on a disc such that for each $H\leq G$ the fixed set is

a disc if $H$ is an extension of a torus by a solvable group;
empty otherwise.

He mentions in the introduction that by other work of his, constructing such actions on discs is equivalent to constructing some finite $G$-CW complex of the same equivariant homotopy type.

The precise reference is Bob Oliver's article Smooth compact Lie group actions on discs, Theorem 4 for a more general statement about certain families which are closed and separating combined with Proposition 8 showing that the aforementioned family is closed and separating.

This happens if and only if the Weyl group of every solvable subgroup is trivial.
For one direction, use the tom Dieck splitting and the fact that the classifying space of a nontrivial finite group is never finitely dominated.
Conversely, if these Weyl groups are all trivial then $G/H$ has no automorphisms as a $G$-space. Inducting up the lattice if subgroups, we see that your space is a finite colimit of representanbles as a pre sheaf on the orbit category. So it’s not only finitely dominated— it’s finite.

Er— something is weird. The trivial subgroup is always solvable and always has nontrivial Weyl group, so if what I wrote is right then this never happens. Maybe I’m wrong in thinking that taking suspension spectra and passing to fixed points should preserve compactness…

Yes! Genuine fixed points do not preserve compact objects. For example, the genuine fixed points of the unit in $\mathrm{Sp}_G$ (which is compact) contains the suspension spectrum of $BG$ as a retract (which is not compact), by the tom Dieck splitting.

What is the Weyl group of an abstract subgroup $H$ of an abstract group $G$?  Is it $N_G(H)/H$?

Exactly. That is how the terminology is used in the context of the tom Dieck splitting, as opposed to in the theory of Lie algebras.

I voted this answer down not because it has a mistake — I make plenty of those myself! — but because, even if it were correct, the description “your space is a finite colimit of representables as a pre sheaf on the orbit category” would mean absolutely nothing to me. (Contrast with the very clear description of the space for $A_5$ in the question.) i can guess what it might mean, but then I have no idea why it would be acyclic.

@HJRW I'm thinking of G-spaces (via Elmendorff's theorem) as presheaves of spaces on the orbit category. My finite colimits are $\infty$-categorical. So a point-set translation of that statement is literally the statement that the space is a finite G-CW complex. The idea was supposed to be that the conditions implied that the slice of the orbit category over $G/H$ for $H$ solvable was a poset (which I now see simply can't be right), so that you could form the pushouts in the presheaf category just as in this poset. Anyway, yeah, my answer is nonsense, but it's still worth learning Elmendorff.

Thanks for the explanation. After a couple of attempts, I found this nice account of Elmendorff’s theorem, and managed to figure out the statement. https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2018/06/elmendorfs_theorem.html . It may be useful to organise one’s thinking about topological groups, but for discrete groups, this looks like a tautology that isn’t going to help much. Note that, as in the $A_5$ example, it requires an actual construction to build one of these spaces!

@HJRW Elmendorff, along with the stable version cf. Guillou-May,  is the foundation for modern equivariant homotopy theory. For instance, the solution of the Kervaire invariant one problem (Hill-Hopkins-Ravenel) is based on $C_2\times C_2 \times C_2$-equivariant homotopy theory. The appendix of that paper is actually a good source for this stuff. For a modern textbook account see Blumberg.

Well, since it's so important I am glad it is now on my radar! Nevertheless, I would be amazed and very pleasantly surprised if any arguments as "soft" as the one you attempted could be used to construct finite acyclic complexes with interesting group actions.
